# ReCaptcha Monthly Quota Exceed Behavior

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, quota

I have implemented **ReCaptcha V2** on a site of mine, that has a significant traffic.

I know for a fact, that the monthly quota of ReCaptcha is *1.000.000*.

I want to know, that in case the quota is surpassed, what is the response from the ReCaptcha?
Is it going to be marked as 'success' and have a server/client validation occur as expected?
Is it going to return an error and do not allow user to submit forms (where we use the ReCaptcha)?

On their official documentation, i did not find anything that can help me answer this questions, except the following:

> If a v2 site key exceeds its monthly quota, then the following or a similar message may be displayed to users in the reCAPTCHA widget for the remainder of the month: `This site is exceeding reCAPTCHA quota.` Before quota is enforced, site owners will be notified by email three times and given at least 90 days to migrate to reCAPTCHA Enterprise.

Either way, i would really like some light shed in the case, if anyone of you bumped upon this case recently and can inform all of the community what the response from ReCaptcha are in this case, how the module appears on the page, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Google may or may not choose to cap your account at 1M. When they do choose to enforce the 1M maximum, they will allow every request to go through as success, `0.9` score, and there will be a message on the site (I believe in the console) saying `Monthly Quota Exceeded` or something similar.

From a captcha competitor, they mentioned that after you receive a 90 day notice, after the 90 days, a random day will come where the quota is enforced and things stop working. I have just passed this 90 day notice and passed the quota and it's still working. Although I plan to use this competitor as a back up and implement other captcha-usage reducing strategies.

Comment: Google recaptcha FAQ (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq) saying that error message `"Over free quota."`will be returned by the "site_verify" response (no console) for the V3. For V2 similar message may be displayed to users in the reCAPTCHA widget (console) for the remainder of the month: `This site is exceeding reCAPTCHA quota.`.